# Modify a specific line in Ansible

Tags: ansible, grub

How to update a line in /etc/default/grub using Ansible from ->

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet console=ttyS0,1100"
```

I tried the following -

```
      - name: Updating of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
        lineinfile:
          path: "/etc/default/grub"
          regexp: "^(.*GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX.*)$"
          line: '\1 console=ttyS0,1100"'
```

but it just added `console=ttyS0,1100"` to the end of sentence leading to an extra " (from the existing sentence).

```
quiet" console=ttyS0,1100"
```

Any help?

Comment: Please don't blindly apply tags, this has nothing to do with Python or Linux-specific APIs.

Comment: Just for the record, there is an other similar question about [How to configure GRUB2 Boot Loader Settings via Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73530296/) with two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the data into a list. For example,

```yaml
  grub_add:
    - {key: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, value: 'console=ttyS0,1100'}
```

Given the file for testing

```ini
shell> cat grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
```

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: '{{ playbook_dir }}/grub'
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}\s*="(?!.*{{ item.value }})(.*)"$'
        line: '{{ item.key }}="\1 {{ item.value }}"'
      loop: "{{ grub_add }}"
```

- You have to enable [*backrefs*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-backrefs) to reference the capture group in *line*.
- The *regexp* will match if the *value* is not present. See the item 'negative lookahead assertion' below

```
^ ....................... the beginning of the string
\s* ..................... 0 or more whitespace
{{ item.key }} .......... the key
\s* ..................... 0 or more whitespace
=" ...................... it is what you think it is
(?!.*{{ item.value }}) .. negative lookahead assertion; matches if the value is not present
(.*)" ................... the capture group followed by the double-quote
$ ....................... the end of the string
```

- The *value* will be appended to the line if not already present.
- Use [Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style). You don't have to escape the special characters.

Run the play with *--check --diff* options

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
--- before: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-130/grub (content)
+++ after: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-130/grub (content)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
+GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet console=ttyS0,1100"

changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'console=ttyS0,1100'})
```

---

The task is idempotent. There will be no changes when you repeat it.

---

Example of the project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── grub
├── grub.orig
├── hosts
└── pb.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
```

Example of a complete playbook. Test adding all parameters to the list

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    grub_add:
      - {key: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, value: 'audit=1'}
      - {key: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, value: 'crashkernel=auto'}
      - {key: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, value: 'rhgb'}
      - {key: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, value: 'quiet'}
      - {key: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, value: 'console=ttyS0,1100'}

  tasks:

    - lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: '{{ playbook_dir }}/grub'
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}\s*="(?!.*{{ item.value }})(.*)"$'
        line: '{{ item.key }}="\1 {{ item.value }}"'
      loop: "{{ grub_add }}"
```

gives running with *--check --diff* options

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'audit=1'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'crashkernel=auto'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'rhgb'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'quiet'})
--- before: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-130/grub (content)
+++ after: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-130/grub (content)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
+GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet console=ttyS0,1100"

changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'console=ttyS0,1100'})

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'audit=1'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'crashkernel=auto'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'rhgb'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'quiet'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'console=ttyS0,1100'})

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The result

```ini
shell> cat grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="audit=1 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet console=ttyS0,1100"
```

The playbook is idempotent

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'audit=1'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'crashkernel=auto'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'rhgb'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'quiet'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX', 'value': 'console=ttyS0,1100'})

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to get at the commandline, use this regex to digest to the input:

```
^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="(.*)"$
```

This now gives you the actual value in `\1`, so you can write the output as:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="\1 console=ttyS0,1100"
```

Of course, you have to escape the double quotes properly for the format of the file you have there.