# Ansible lineinfile - add substring only if missing

Tags: string, file, text, ansible, insert

I'm trying to disable transparent_hugepage in the kernel. Which according to [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1320153) article means adding the substring `transparent_hugepage=never` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable in `/etc/default/grub`.

My attempt at doing that looks like:

```
- name: disable transparent_hugepage
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/default/grub
    regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="[^"]+)"'
    line: '\g<1> transparent_hugepage=never"'
    backrefs: yes
```

That however adds the substring every time ansible runs, not only when it is missing.

i.e.

```
# grep CMD /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/cs-swap rd.lvm.lv=cs/root rd.lvm.lv=cs/swap rhgb quiet transparent_hugepage=never transparent_hugepage=never"
```

Surely there must be a better way to handle that than trying to do something fancy with regex negative lookahead?

I tried the lookahead approach using:

```
regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="[^"]+)(?! transparent_hugepage=never)"'
```

but it behaves the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Surely there must be a better way to handle that ...***

To ensure that THP is disabled before other services starts, one should create a service file which disables THP during boot up. This is the recommend approach by certain Open Source Projects, one in example is [MongoDB - Disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/).

Placing a service file

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP)

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled && echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

on a Remote Node via

```yaml
- name: Create a service file in order to disable THP automatically
  copy: 
    src: disable-thp.service
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/disable-thp.service
```

than, a task will do the job

```yaml
- name: Make sure Transparent Huge Pages (THP) are disabled
  systemd:
    state: started
    enabled: yes
    name: disable-thp
```

Double checking on CLI result into an output of

```bash
systemctl status disable-thp
○ disable-thp.service - Disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/disable-thp.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2024-03-01 10:00:00 CET; 11 days ago
   Duration: 39ms
    Process: 884 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c echo 'never' > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled && ...
   Main PID: 884 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 4ms

cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]

cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
always defer defer+madvise madvise [never]
```

**Further Readings**

- [How to use, monitor, and disable transparent hugepages in Red Hat Enterprise Linux ... on-the-fly?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/46111)
- [Disable Transparent Hugepages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/)
- For something like Splunk: [How do I disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP) and confirm that it is disabled?](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Monitoring-Splunk/How-do-I-disable-Transparent-Huge-Pages-THP-and-confirm-that-it/m-p/124490)
- For Percona PostgreSQL: [Disabling THP with `systemd` in Ubuntu](https://www.percona.com/blog/transparent-huge-pages-refresher/)

Comment: nice - clearly one way to do it, but it goes against the grains of the distro - would like to see the change reflected in the file mentioned in the docs. surely there must be a way to add a substring to a line?

Comment: "_... but it goes against the grains of the distro - would like to see the change reflected in the file mentioned in the docs ..._", the example shown is from production systems running RHEL 7, 8 and 9 ... That approach was preferred because there is no need to "edit" file(s) and! necessarly rebuild the kernel boot image afterwards. Your linked Red Hat Solution KB article also mentioned this second option "_... create a customized tuned profile with disabled THP ..._".

Comment: If you still want to edit the GRUB bootloader config you may have a look into [Add string in middle of line (Ansible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73530296/).